# Getting the biggest(or highest) letter

Tags: javascript

If we want to get the max or min value we use `Math.max` or `Math.min` . I wonder if there is a way to get the highest letter.

For example;

```
var i = 'A';
var ii = 'B';
var iii = 'C';

result = getthemax(i , ii, iii);   
// so result equels to 'C'
```

I searched a lot but can't find anything like this. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Create an array and assign the letters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply put them in an array, then use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and then [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the last item from the array:

```
var i = 'A';
var ii = 'B';
var iii = 'C';

var highestLetter = [i, ii, iii].sort().pop(); //will now be "C".
```

A function that would do this would be:

```
function getthemax() {
    return Array.prototype.pop.call(Array.prototype.sort.call(arguments));
}
getthemax(i, ii, iii); //"C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but not the best in my opinion, is play with the ASCII characters.

A quick example:

```
var i = 'A';
var ii = 'B';
var iii = 'C';

var r = Math.max(i.charCodeAt(0), ii.charCodeAt(0), iii.charCodeAt(0))

var biggest = String.fromCharCode(r);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: Please link to English documentation only. Stackoverflow is an English site, so you can't expect us all to understand Spanish.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
var i1 = i.charCodeAt();
var ii1 = ii.charCodeAt();
var iii1 = iii.charCodeAt();
result = Math.max(i1, ii1, iii1);
```

Comment: There's 2 problems with this answer: 1) This is the exact same approach as José Cabo is using in his answer; 2) It's missing the conversion back from charCode to letter.